# Is it possible to have multiple SSH keys?

Tags: ssh-keys

I would like to generate multiple SSH keys for my different servers.

For example:

- 1 RSA 2048 public/private key for 1.1.1.1
- 1 ECC public/private key for 2.2.2.3
- 1 ECC public/private key for 3.3.3.3

I understand the ssh keys are stored in the .ssh folder, but how can I copy the right public keys to the correct servers, and how can I generate multiple SSH keys without writing each-other over? I have read something about the -c command, but do not fully understand if it is able to do what I am requesting.

Comment: Short answer: **Yes** ... longer answer: ssh tries all keys listed in `ssh-add -l` ... as well as the default identities listed in `~/.ssh/` ... **On Copying keys** : Try `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: when i create a ssh key will it give the ssh key a unique id, or can i name it myself?

Comment: Crossdupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419566/best-way-to-use-multiple-ssh-private-keys-on-one-client (but you need to look at more than the first answer). `-c` is not a command; as an option on `ssh` or `ssh-keygen` it does (different) things completely unrelated to what you want; as an option on `ssh-add` it could work but would be very clumsy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple SSH keys. 
I would suggest reading the man page for ssh-keygen:
http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-keygen.1?query=ssh-keygen%26sec=1

Use the -f option to specify your own filename.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f myfirstrsakey
```

Comment: And to _use_ this keyfile, `ssh -i file` or `IdentityFile file` in a `Host` section in `.ssh/ssh_config` per the crossdupe I linked above.